# How to create set of images (~1000) from single image , by creating different variations?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, image-segmentation

I am new to Image Processing. I have certain set of unique images. I need to create different variation of same image so that I can use that set of variations to train neural network. I need to do this as I dont have enough number of images for each category. Does any one have any clue how can I start ?

I have some ideas like, image dimensions, image angle can be changed to create variation but I am not sure if that will really help neural network.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try Image Augmentation Technique which involves Flipping, Rotating and Scaling of an image.

If you are using Keras, You can use ImageDataGenerator.

```
keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator
```